# on or in correct preposition

Tags: sentence-construction

> I forgot to turn on the switch after putting my phone on charger.

Is that sentence correct grammatically, phone on charger or phone in charger which preposition is correct thanks in advance for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are incorrect. We never say "to put phone on charger" or "to put a phone in charger" in terms of charging phone's battery. You could say "I put my phone on a charger", but that would mean the phone is lying on top of a charging device.

I think the correct expression with regard to your situation is "to plug in the phone." So, you should say:

> I forgot to turn on the switch after plugging in my phone.

or

> I forgot to turn on the switch after plugging in my phone to the
>   charger.

Sometimes people say instead:

> I forgot to turn on the switch after putting my phone **on charge**.

I don't know exactly if it is standard English. It looks more like colloquial speech. However, "my phone is on charge" seems to be a totally valid construction.